# Why are there only two moderator positions available?

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

Well, we're in the primary phase of the election process, and I looked up at the positions available. I did a double take upon seeing that there were but two positions open. Now, every SE site that I've seen (as far as I can remember) has had three moderators. So then, why are there only two positions available? Are we down-sizing along with the rest of the economy?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The newly elected moderators are not going to replace the existing ones; they are added to them. This means we will have five moderators, after this election.

The number of available positions depends on the needs of the site; if a site requires more moderators, then more positions are available.

As far as I have seen, the minimum number of available positions is one. I have never seen this happen, but it could also be that an election is not held, if there is no need for new moderators.

Comment: I understand now. One other question, when are moderators replaced?

Comment: They are replaced when they are not anymore active on the site where they are moderators, or when they announce to retire.

Comment: So moderators are elected for life? That might change things...

Comment: @AndrewLeach Let's say there isn't a prefixed limit for how long a user can be a moderator. It is more probable they lose interest in being moderators, or they don't have anymore the motivation for being moderators.